# Consuming web service with android xamarin

Tags: c#, android, web-services, soap, xamarin

I have built an app: click on the button then it gives out a sentence from HelloWorld(). I have put my web service on IIS and it works well. I can access the web service on browsers and on my emulator also, when I change "localhost" to my IPv4 address. Everything is working fine. But when I deploy the app, it gives back the Exceptions: ConnectionFailure (connection refused). Do you know how to solve this problem? I add my web service as web reference. I don't know why it still can't work. Have been stuck for this for 2 weeks. Please help me. Thanks a lot.

This my code connecting to the web service in Android app:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);            
            Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);
            TextView txt = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);
            button.Click += delegate
            {
                WebReference.websv connect = new WebReference.websv();
                connect.Url = "http://192.168.xxx.xxx/tigonkhung.com/websv.asmx";
                txt.Text = connect.HelloWorld();

            };

        }
```

[This is the web service in the emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bjIw.png)

Comment: Still using "asmx"? Go with rest, your life will be much easier.

Answer (score 0):

I used the tutorial on Xamarin's website when I was learning. Take a look at this tutorial [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/web_services/) to see if it helps. I must mention that i was using WCF however.